# How to see if any link in WebBrowser contains string? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, process, browser

I am building a web browser and if a link is clicked, if that link contains a certain string then I want a different program to open:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigated
If WebBrowser1.Document.Links.Contains("STRING") Then
        Process.Start("PROGRAM I WANT TO OPEN")
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
If InStr(e.Url.ToString, "String") Then
   Process.Start("Program I want to open")
End if
```